# The Non-Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Everyone knows the **Pythagorean theorem**: In a  right-angled triangle, the square of the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides.

> **The Pythagorean Theorem:** $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Recently, professor Halfbrain has proved a theorem that he calls the **Non-Pythagorean theorem**. This theorem considers a right-angled triangle, in which the two sides adjacent to the right angle have lengths $a$ and $b$ (just as in the classical Pythagorean theorem), together with a mysterious quantity that the professor calls $x$.

> **The Non-Pythagorean Theorem:** $$a^{-2}+b^{-2}=x^{-2}$$

This puzzle asks: What's the geometric role of this mysterious quantity $x$ in the right-angled triangle?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> $x$ is the altitude $h$ from side $c$.

Explanation:

> $a^{-2} + b^{-2} = \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2 b^2} = \frac{c^2}{a^2 b^2},$
>
>  hence $x = \frac{ab}{c}$. 
>  The area of the triangle is $\frac{ab}{2}=\frac{ch}{2}$, so $x=h$.

Comment: Vey nicely done!